# React Hosted on S3 And aws-sdk Access

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a React app that is hosted in an S3 bucket.
The app uses AWS Cognito for authentication.
Here is the useEffect that runs when the app loads to initialize the AWS SDK:

```js
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
    ...
    useEffect(() => { 

        const options = {
            region: import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_REGION!,
            credentials: new AWS.Credentials({
                accessKeyId: import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!,
                secretAccessKey: import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_SECRET_KEY!,
            }),
        }
        AWS.config.update(options);
    }, []);
    ...
```

The issue is that I can't load the environment variables without exposing them to the end user (like from .env file).
What is the best way to handle this kind of issues without exposing my credentials?

p.s

I tried looking into Cognito Hosted UI feature but I rather not get into it if that's an option

Comment: Why aren't you using AWS Amplify to connect to cognito?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/authenticate-react-application-users-by-using-amazon-cognito-and-aws-amplify.html